# SQL Srver foreign key error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I have this assignment for beginning sql server to add foreign keys to these tables. The last `ALTER TABLE` command always throws an error

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'TCases' that match the referencing column list...

and I really can't figure out why it's giving this error. Any insight is appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE TCourtRooms
(        intCourtRoomID             INTEGER         NOT NULL
        ,strCourtRoomNumber         VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
        ,strJudgeLastName           VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
        ,strJudgeFirstName          VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
        ,CONSTRAINT TCourtDockets_PK PRIMARY KEY (intCourtRoomID)
)

CREATE TABLE TCases
(        intCourtRoomID             INTEGER         NOT NULL
        ,intCaseIndex               INTEGER         NOT NULL    
        ,strCaseNumber              VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
        ,strDescription             VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
        ,CONSTRAINT TCases_PK PRIMARY KEY (intCourtRoomID, intCaseIndex)
)

CREATE TABLE TPersons
(        intCourtRoomID             INTEGER         NOT NULL
        ,intCaseIndex               INTEGER         NOT NULL
        ,intPersonIndex             INTEGER         NOT NULL
        ,strLastName                VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
        ,strFirstName               VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
        ,strPersonRole              VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL        --Options are plaintiff or defendant
        ,CONSTRAINT TPlaintiffs_PK PRIMARY KEY (intCourtRoomID, intCaseIndex, intPersonIndex)
  )


CREATE TABLE TLawyers
(        intLawyerID                INTEGER         NOT NULL
        ,intCaseIndex               INTEGER         NOT NULL
        ,intPersonIndex             INTEGER         NOT NULL
        ,strLastName                VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
        ,strFirstName               VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
        ,strLawyerRole              VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL  --plaintiff or defendant
        ,CONSTRAINT TLawyers_PK PRIMARY KEY (intLawyerID, intCaseIndex, intPersonIndex)
        ,CONSTRAINT TLawyers_intLawyerID_strLawyerRole_UN   UNIQUE (intLawyerID, strLawyerRole)
)
```

Problem 3.2 Identify and create foreign keys

```
-- Child                    Parent          Column(s)
-- -----                    ------          ---------
-- TCases                   TCourtRooms     intCourtRoomID
-- TPersons                 TCases          intCourtRoomID, intCaseIndex
-- TLawyers                 TCourtRooms



ALTER TABLE TCases
    ADD CONSTRAINT TCases_TCourtRooms_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (intCourtRoomID) REFERENCES TCourtRooms (intCourtRoomID)

ALTER TABLE TPersons
    ADD CONSTRAINT TPersons_TCases_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (intCourtRoomID, intCaseIndex) REFERENCES TCases (intCourtRoomID, intCaseIndex)

ALTER TABLE TLawyers
    ADD CONSTRAINT TLawyers_TCases_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (intCaseIndex) REFERENCES TCases (intCaseIndex)</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the primary key for `TCases`:

```
   CONSTRAINT TCases_PK PRIMARY KEY (intCourtRoomID, intCaseIndex)
```

It is a *composite* primary key, with two parts.  You need to include both keys in the declaration:

```
ALTER TABLE TLawyers
    ADD CONSTRAINT TLawyers_TCases_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (intCaseIndex) REFERENCES TCases (intCourtRoomId, intCaseIndex)
```

But, alas, you cannot because the field `TLawyers.intCourtRoomId` does not exist.  I'm not sure what you should do:

- Add the field to `TLawyers`.
- Fix the primary key definition to reference only one column.
- Do something else.

But that is your problem.